# How to parse tuple into several properties?

Tags: python, django

In my django app I do calculations on model side, for this i use only one function that returns a tuple. I want to parse this tuple into several properties

But I cant since -

> TypeError: 'property' object is not iterable

```
def _get_total(self):
    from inventory.models import Inventory
    inventory_quantity = Inventory.objects.filter(material=self.id, is_active = True ).aggregate(Sum('quantity'))

    from purchase.models import POmaterial     
    po_quantity = POmaterial.objects.filter(material=self.id, is_active = True).aggregate(Sum('quantity'))

    from sales.models import SOproduct
    so_quantity =  SOproduct.objects.filter(product__material=self.id ,  is_active=True ).aggregate(Sum('quantity'))  


    actual_quantity = inventory_quantity + po_quantity - so_quantity

    min_deficit = self.min_quantity - actual_quantity

    max_deficit = self.max_quantity - actual_quantity



    return  inventory_quantity, po_quantity, so_quantity, min_deficit , max_deficit




 total_inventory,  total_po, total_so,min_deficit, max_deficit   = property(_get_total())
```

any ideas how can I create all 5 properties from this tuple?

Comment: Properties need to call back to a single "getter" so you are out of luck. If the reason for not providing 5 individual properties is efficiency, try to use [caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/cache/), but think hard about the invalidation policy, first.

Comment: Thanks, Yeah , since I can not use the property value i already have  in next calculation method it looks like there is no way I can reuse something I already calculated and each time same recalculation is required,  if I want to keep all calculations  on model side. I find this is a  limitation .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does the following code provide the necessary functionality?

```
class MyClass(ClassParent):

   _total_inventory = None
   _total_po = None
   ...
   ...

   def _get_total_(self):
   ...
   # everything before the return clause
   self._total_inventory = inventory_quantity
   self._total_po = po_quantity
   ...

   @property
   def total_inventory(self):
       if self._total_inventory is None:
           self._get_total()
       return self._total_inventory

   @property
   def total_po(self):
       if self._total_po is None:
           self._get_total()
       return self._total_po
   ...
   # And so on
```

Comment: Yes thank you. So if I understand correctly if the method is not called then the _total_inventory will be always None. So this way it will be each time recalculated.